# Withdraw suggested edit

Tags: support, editing, review

Is it possible to withdraw a suggested edit? How?

Background: I was looking for a requirements management tool with my private account (for my hobby projects) and now I'm looking for the same thing again for my company with my company account. I accidentally edited the question, so it went into the review queue.

I should not do this for various reasons, mainly because it's not entirely clear that it's still the OP posting. It might look like someone else doing vandalism or trying to ask a similar question with slightly changed requirements. Also for the +2 rep (but it's very hard to avoid edit reps anyway), the noise in the review queue and potentially lots of other reasons.

So I wonder whether it would have been possible to withdraw my changes instead of relying on others to reject it in the review queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar question on the main meta site:  [Undo edit suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125730/236563).

The answer is that, no, you cannnot retract a suggested edit.
It appears that you will have to wait for the expected rejection to come through.